# ASP.NET Core FindByAsync doesn't load navigation properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have an AppUser class in an ASP.NET Core 2.0 application using EF 2.0

The user can send and receive messages, and I have a method that gets the latest date of the latest message, if any:

```
    public IEnumerable<Message> MessagesSent { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Message> MessagesReceived { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfLastMessage()
    {       
        var sentDate = new DateTime();
        var receivedDate = new DateTime();
        if (MessagesSent != null)
        {
            sentDate = this.MessagesSent.Select(x => x.Created).Last();
        }
        if (MessagesReceived != null)
        {
            receivedDate = this.MessagesReceived.Select(x => x.Created).Last();
        }


        return (sentDate > receivedDate ? sentDate : receivedDate);
    }
```

However when I load the user using:

```
_userManager.FindByIdAsync(relevantContact).Result;
```

Then the navigation properties aren't loaded so the DateOfLastMessage function will alway be the DateTime min value.

How do I resolve this?  (and as an aside, can my method be simplified ... ?)

Comment: Why are using `IEnumerable` for navigational properties? Should it be just `List`? Take a look at [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) about navigational properties.

Comment: OT: Why do you use `.Result` ? (You shouldn't).

Comment: Which Navigation properties?  The connection between your 2 code snippets is unclear. Document it a lot better, or create a [mcve]

Comment: @IgorYalovoy Thanks for the tip

Comment: @HenkHolterman I use result as I need the user as a paramater for the next query (not shown). Is there a better way?

Comment: @RobbieMills *all* examples, samples and courses on ASP.NET MVC, Core or not,  use `await` to await for asynchronous methods to return. The only place you find `.Result` is in SO questions, typically about deadlocks,  with people commenting `don't use .Result`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `_userManager` doesn't know or care about additional navigational properties you have in your User class.

If you want those properties loaded you have a few options.

- Use the queryable `_userManager.Users.Include(x => x.MessagesSent).Include(x => x.MessagesReceived)`.
- Create your own `UserManager` and override the `FindByIdAsync()` method and register it for dependency injection.
- Use the `DbContext` to directly query the `Users` data.

Comment: You forgot [explicit loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#explicit-loading) and [lazy-loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading), but later requires to add the loading code manually in your property. Will not be required in the next version